# Spawning an array

Tags: ruby

Not sure that my question is correct, but in general I would do the following:

Given a code snippet like:

```
[{ <some events>, "close"}, { <some other events>, "close"}].each do |events|
    it "should handle events" do
        ...
    end
    ...
end
```

I would like to augment the events' array. Say there are 2 ways to *close*: `"close"` (same) and `"stop"`. Which means, I would like to write some code that will check 4 sequences: `[{<some events>, "close"}, {<some other events>, "close"}, {<some events>, "stop"}, {<some other events>, "stop"}]`.

What would be the proper (well-styled in Ruby) way to code it?

**Update**: the `<some events>` and `<some other events>` are sequences of strings (this is just to clarify).

**Update N2:** `stop` and `close` in a more general case can appear in the middle of the sequence as well.

**Update N3:** it just *might* be that having a single final sequence at `do` will be more convenient. I might be wrong here.

**Update N4:** Example (just to make it all clear):

> initial messages: "open", "click_btn1", "click_btn2", 
>   "open", "click_btn2", "click_btn3",
>
> desired result: "open", "click_btn1", "click_btn2", "close" "open",
>   "click_btn1", "click_btn2", "close" "open", "click_btn2",
>   "click_btn3", "stop" "open", "click_btn2", "click_btn3", "stop"

Comment: Those are not valid Ruby objects.

Comment: Is `it "should handle events"` supposed to be some sort of unit test?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: yes, definitely

Answer (score 2):

Just have nested iterations.

```
[some_events, some_other_events].each do |event|
  ["close", "stop"].each do |close_or_stop|
    ...
  end
end
```

Or maybe

```
[some_events, some_other_events].product(
["close", "stop"]) do |event, close_or_stop|
  ...
end
```

Comment: this is great! however, the "close", "stop" are not necessarily coming as the closing message (in my more general case). also, I would like to have a final array at `do`. Is it possible please?

Comment: You can have an array by doing to_a right after product but you would generally like to avoid creating extra arrays since that is extra calculation.

Comment: it might be some misunderstanding about the question objectives - just added **update N4** with an explicit example. could you have a look please?